# Выдача наград запросом

Tags: php, mysqli

помогите составить запрос на выдачу наград за участие в конкурсе. Нужно по окончанию конкурса выдать награды но только первым трем у кого значение gifts больше чем у остальных 17-ти одну награду к примеру 100 а, остальным по 50. Как такое реализовать?

Comment: Через `SELECT ... WHERE ...`. Покажите ваш запрос для начала

Comment: select * from `$table_users` where gifts>1 order by `gifts` desc limit 1,20 так вывожу список

Comment: Ув. знатоки помогите пожалуйста...